# Nerve and deformation retracts

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let consider an open cover $C=\{U_{i},i\in I\}$ of a topological space $X$. Suppose that all intersections of sets in $C$ are contractible or empty. Consider $N(C)$ the nerve associated to $C$. By nerve theorems, we know that $N(C)$ is homotopy equivalent to $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}U_{i}$.

But can we always construct $\mathcal{S}$, a geometric realization of $N(C)$, such that $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}U_{i}$ deformation retracts onto $\mathcal{S}$ ? Do we need stronger conditions on the covering ?

Comment: Typically, the nerve has higher dimension than $X$ and, thus, you cannot even embed $S$ in $X$. Work out an example when $X=[0,1]$.